# Python: using a List Comprehensions instead of loop in order to improve the performance

Tags: python, performance, optimization, list-comprehension

I have a type from a dictionary (example)

```
l =('1037_97',["a","b","c","d","e"])
```

I wish to save a file (las format) but [Liblas](http://www.liblas.org/tutorial/python.html) can write only single point.

```
for l in Groups.iteritems():
    for p in xrange(len(l[1])):
        file_out.write(l[1][p])
```

I am trying to use *if it's possible* a List Comprehensions in order to save code and speed the loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a shorter solution, consider using `map()` for inner cycle, or even for both. But it is unlikely to get a significant performance boost. However, `for p in l[1]:` still may be faster than that construction with `xrange`. The following example should do what you wanted in a single line:

```
map(lambda g: map(file_out.write, g), groups.itervalues())
```

Now let's compare performance of different implementations. Here I tried to measure times on some test data:

```
import timeit

groups = dict(('1037_%d' % i, ["a","b","c","d","e"]) for i in xrange(100))

class FOut(object):
    def write(self, v):
        #print v
        pass

file_out = FOut()

def using_map():
    map(lambda g: map(file_out.write, g), groups.itervalues())

def initial_version():
    for l in groups.iteritems():
        for p in xrange(len(l[1])):
            file_out.write(l[1][p])

def seq_iteration():
    for l in groups.iteritems():
        for p in l[1]:
            file_out.write(p)

def seq_iteration_values():
    for l in groups.itervalues():
        for p in l:
            file_out.write(p)

def list_compr():
    [[file_out.write(v) for v in g] for g in groups.itervalues()]



tests = ('initial_version', 'using_map', 'seq_iteration', 'list_compr', 'seq_iteration_values')


for test in tests:
    print test, timeit.timeit('%s()'%test, 'from __main__ import %s'%test, number=10000)
```

And the result is:

```
initial_version 0.862531900406
using_map 0.703296899796
seq_iteration 0.541372060776
list_compr 0.632550954819
seq_iteration_values 0.493131160736
```

As you can see, your initial version is the slowest, fixing iteration helps a lot, `map()` version is short, but not as fast as the version with `itervalues()`. List comprehension that creates unneeded lists is not bad, but still slower than the plain cycle.

Comment: Thanks Ellioh. Could i ask why xrange cold be slow?

Comment: Because you make an extra operation: first get a number from sequence, then get a value by index (or even get value by index twice, as there are two indices). Iterating items one-by-one is highly optimized and should be slightly faster.

Answer (score 10):

Loop comprehensions do not necessarily speed up a loop. They only speed up a loop if the *end result* should be a list. List comprehensions are faster than creating an empty list and appending to it one by one.

In your case, you want to write items to a file, and not create a new list. The list creation cost is then wasted.

You don't need the `xrange()` call though, just loop over `l[1]`. You don't need `.iteritems()` either, as you ignore the keys. Use `.itervalues()` instead:

```
for lst in Groups.itervalues():
    for p in lst:
        file_out.write(p)
```

I used `lst` as a loop variable; `l` is easily confused for `i` in many fonts.

Comment: Dear Martijn thanks. Your solution give me this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\liblas\file.py", line 379, in write
    'be of type liblas.point.Point' % pt)
LASException: cannot write 2, it must be of type liblas.point.Point

Comment: and lst is only the key ('1037_97') without the element ( ["a","b","c","d","e"])

Comment: @Gianni: Sorry; I thought and meant `.itervalues()`, my mistake.

Comment: don't problem and thanks, your posts are always great. I was testing .itervalues() and it works well.